# The autoloader expected class tobe defined in file

Tags: php, symfony, classloader

I know that this question have been asked many times but I don't found a solution on the Web  who correspond to my problem.
So, I've create a UserBundle and when I try to access to the login page, I have the following error:

> The autoloader expected class "ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\lab/src\ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

I've check my file if my namespace or my class name are good, but I can't find the mistake.

My SecurityController :

```
<?php

namespace ET\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller{
public function loginAction(Request $request){

    // Si le visiteur est déjà identifié, on le redirige vers l'accueil
    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted(IS_AUTHENTIFICATED_REMEMBERED)){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('et_home'));
    }

    $session = $request->getSession();

    // On vérifie qu'il n'y a pas d'erreurs lors d'un précédente soumission de formulaire
    if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTIFICATION_ERROR)){
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTIFICATION_ERROR);
    }else{
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTIFICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTIFICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('ETUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username'  => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'          => $error,
    ));
}
}
```

My firewall :

```
    firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    # the login page has to be accessible for everybody
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  true
        provider:   in_memory
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /
```

My router :

```
login:
     pattern:   /login
     defaults:  { _controller: ETUserBundle:Security:login }

 login_check:
     pattern:  /login_check

logout:
   pattern:   /logout
```

If anyone have an idea for me please. Thanks in advance.
I've tried this on Symfony 2.6 and 2.7, with a new installation.

Comment: What is the path of `SecurityController.php` ?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\lab\src\ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\

Comment: Your namespace should be `ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller` ,Bundle after ET

Comment: Ok, it works, thank you :) I just don't understand why they add the Bundle folder but ok ^^

Comment: You have to follow docs correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

replace `namespace ET\UserBundle\Controller;`by `namespace ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController`

Comment: Actually, replace it with namespace ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller. The answer is in the error message. Suggesting the path it resolved does not meet your definition. Compare the directory structure with your namespace and they will usually match (unless namespaces are mapped).